# Android- Click goes to a ListView in a clickable RelativeLayout instead of the RL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My app has several `RelativeLayout`s with a `TextView` and a `ListView` in each. I've made the `RelativeLayout`s clickable (and it works well). The problem is, the `ListView`s that are embedded in them are also clickable, and whenever the user tries to click the area of the `RelativeLayout` with the list, the click registers for the list instead.

I've tried setting the `ListView`s as `clickable="false"` and `focusable="false"`. I've tried `descendantsFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the `RelativeLayout`s. Those don't work.

What's the solution? This is my first app, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making the lists' items' onItemClick methods mimic the onClick method of their parent RelativeLayout.

If the parent RelativeLayout would lead to fragmentA, then each item in its child list also leads to fragmentA.

This feels a bit half-baked and cheap, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware if you have not defined the listView objects to have the android:onClick attribute="" then they should not respond to click events. However, setting them to clickable="false" won't hurt.

The easiest way to manage onClick events in an android activity is to define each view in the layout that should be monitored for click events in this way :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.ITEM1 :
              //Insert stuff to do when clicked here
          break;
          case R.id.ITEM2 :
              //Insert stuff to do when clicked here
          break;
    }
}
```

This method should be implemented on the activity that has the relative layouts and appropriate views defined either programmatically or by XML layouts. If you didn't want to use a switch case you could always substitute for if-else statements with the conditions being along the lines of if(v.getId() == R.id.ITEM_TO_CHECK)...

Cheers,

Jamie

Comment: Thank you, but setting the listviews as clickable="false" doesn't work (nor does focusable="false"); their items are still clickable, and they prevent the RelativeLayout from being clicked.

Comment: why not call the same logic if (v.getId() == layout.getId()) || (v.getId() == list.getId()) ?

Comment: I believe the way the ListView works is that the ListView itself is not the thing you need to stop being clickable, its the items that the ListView holds that need to be surpressed from looking for onClick actions. The ListView itself registers onClick actions but simply determines which item you clicked on and triggers the appropriate event for the item. Maybe if you could surpress the items from looking for onClick events, that might work but then also defeat the point of having a listView.